# pnorm function error message (use Mac OS)(R version is 3.5.2)

Tags: r

The pnorm function in R does not work properly. For the standard normal distribution, the pnorm should be less than 1.

```
> pnorm(1.96)
[1] 1.96 # suppose to be 0.97500

> pnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
Error in pnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) : 
  unused arguments (mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce these outputs. And `pnorm(1.96)` should be `0.97500` and it is, please revise your introductory stats. Also, `pnorm` and other base R functions are used countless times per day, an error like yours is almost always caused by a user error. Try to close and restart R without saving the session and see if it goes away.

Comment: In R you can overwrite constants and functions and this looks as if someone played a trick on you. If you enter just 'pnorm' without a pair of brackets,  what is Rs answer?

Comment: Yes, the 'pnorm' function is overwritten, how could I get the original 'pnorm' function?

Comment: `> pnorm
function(v, p=2) {
  return((sum(abs(v) ** p) ** (1 / p)))
}`

Comment: You can fix this by reassigning the right `pnorm` function to the `pnorm` label: `pnorm <- stats::pnorm`